# Obtaining the charge amount from a stripe token using stripe API

Tags: javascript, php, html, stripe-payments

**The goal:** I have an html page that has two different items you can purchase.  One is $5 and the other is $10.  I'm using stripe to process the payments.  When stripe creates a payment token and submits that to my process_charge.php I'd like to pull the charge amount from the data submitted via POST.  Then I can use that amount to call `Stripe_Charge::create()`.

**The problem:** The amount isn't being submitted to my PHP form and I'm not sure how to get it.

**My temporary solution:** A different php form for every single item I'm selling.  Then a NEW PHP FORM FOR EVERY NEW ITEM!!!  *not ideal*

I'm currently using the embedded form method listed here: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/checkout

My order page looks like this.

```
<div class="payment-options">
    <form action="process_card.php" method="POST">
        <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="pk_test_PUBLIC_KEY_FOR_TESTING"
            data-amount="1000"
            data-name="Nice Lint"
            data-description="High quality belly button lint."
            data-image="images/nice-lint.svg"
            data-panel-label="Checkout {{amount}}"
            data-label="Pay with Credit Card"
            data-billing-address="true"
            data-shipping-address="true">
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

So this works great.  It takes the customer's information, their shipping/billing address and their credit card details.  Then it generates a charge token and submits that to `process_card.php`.  There I can take the token and perform something like this:

```
if ($_POST) {
  Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_SECRET_KEY_FOR_TESTING");
  try {
    if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
      throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
    Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => '1000'],
                                "currency" => "usd",
                                "card" => $_POST['stripeToken']));
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Here I take the token that was submitted via `POST` and send that off to stripe using their API.  The amount, currency, and card token are required fields.  You can see the token is being pulled from the `POST` data but I'm having to send a literal string for the amount.  This is all fine and dandy until I have more than one product/service whatever and I have different forms that generate tokens with different amounts and send them to my `process_card.php`.  Then that literal string isn't looking happy anymore.  His stupid smirk is wiped right off his stupid face.

So anyways, I checked all the `POST` data to see if any of the submitted fields contained the amount so I could pass that along.  So I just did a little loop to see what was submitted:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "key: " . $key . "  -  " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

and it gives me this:

```
key: stripeToken - tok_youShouldDefinitelyPostThisTokenOnAPublicWebsite
key: stripeEmail - super.real.email@aol.com
key: stripeBillingName - asdf
key: stripeBillingAddressLine1 - asdf
key: stripeBillingAddressZip - 12345
key: stripeBillingAddressCity - Schenectady
key: stripeBillingAddressState - NY
key: stripeBillingAddressCountry - United States
key: stripeBillingAddressCountryCode - US
key: stripeShippingName - asdf
key: stripeShippingAddressLine1 - asdf
key: stripeShippingAddressZip - 12345
key: stripeShippingAddressCity - Schenectady
key: stripeShippingAddressState - NY
key: stripeShippingAddressCountry - United States
key: stripeShippingAddressCountryCode - US
```

No amount.  Shucks.  So off to the API docs to see if I can find a solution.  The closest thing I could find was `Stripe_Charge::retrieve({CHARGE_ID});`
 which was found here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#retrieve_charge .  This however only applied to successfully processed charges.

So I'm stuck.  Can't figure it out.  The best solution I could come up with was adding a `<input type="hidden" name="amt" value="1000" />` line inside the embedded form I was provided so I could pull the amount via `$_POST['amt']`.  The problem with this is that I have no idea if it's PCI compliant.  In many places on the stripe site/api/docs they tell you not to include name fields in their forms so you aren't passing sensitive information from page to page on your site, so I figure "better safe than sorry".  Is there an alternate way of handling this or some best practice I'm not aware of?

**Sorry this was so long.  I really put in as much effort as I could to try to solve it on my own and I wanted to provide as much information as I could.

Comment: Was also wondering the same, their checkout example has the amount hardcoded. Looking at doing the same thing with a hidden field with the amount but can't help but think this is wrong and insecure, but will probably do what I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any issue in regards to PCI compliance by putting their price in the form (as long as you're using SSL). However this would allow them to simply edit the HTML input before submitting and getting the item a lot cheaper than you'd want them to. You could get around this by using a database with a products table and reference the product ID in a hidden input field.

Comment: Thanks.  I spent more time in to looking at what is supposed to be protected for PCI compliance.  After perusing through the [official documentation](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php) and after readin through an [informative blog post](http://kencochrane.net/blog/2012/01/developers-guide-to-pci-compliant-web-applications/#credit-card-data-that-can-be-stored) I found it turns out the amount of the transaction isn't considered protected data.

Comment: Also, in regards to someone being able to change the amounts we're not really worried about it.  We're a very very low volume company right now so not enough is automated for something like that to slip by.  If some weird charge went through I believe you can use the Stripe dashboard to refund then we can contact the customer to see if it was a weird error and ask them to redo the charge.  I think the only amount validation I plan on doing is making sure it's a number, and making sure it's > 0.  Thanks a lot for your help.  Wish I could upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this issue by using AJAX for each button generation, sendig data to php file and regenerate the button on selection and when button click every button is unique